# Android graphview not automatically updating

Tags: android

I am using the GraphView Library and I cant get the graph to redraw itself when I update the series (or replace the series with a new one). It only seems to redraw itself when I touch the screen. Here is my update function.

```
private void updateGraph(Animal a)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updating Graph", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    GraphViewData[] newData = new GraphViewData[2];
    newData[0] = new GraphViewData(0,a.getAvg());
    newData[1] = new GraphViewData(1,0.2);

    GraphViewSeries newSeries = new GraphViewSeries(a.getName(),dStyle,newData);

    graph.removeSeries(exampleSeries);
    graph.addSeries(newSeries);
    //update horizontal value
    //graph.setHorizontalLabels(new String[]{a.getName()});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
//test random y value
    double rnd = generator.nextDouble();

    // round is an incremental value (1,2,3...)
    GraphViewData newData = new GraphViewData(round,rnd);

    exampleSeries.appendData(newData, false);
    graph.redrawAll();
```

Comment: This is outdated. The method is currently graph.refreshDrawableState()

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394860/5093841) below using onDataChanged

Answer (score 0):

Use [onDataChanged](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView.html#onDataChanged-boolean-boolean-) to let the graph redraw and recalculate the viewport.

```
graph.onDataChanged(true, true);
```

Be careful with the two parameters `keepLabelsSize` and `keepViewport` . As the Javadoc says:

> - @param **keepLabelsSize**
>     true if you don't want to recalculate the size of the labels. It is recommended to use "true" because this will improve performance and prevent a flickering.
> - @param **keepViewport**
>     true if you don't want that the viewport will be recalculated. It is recommended to use "true" for performance.

Anyway, keep in mind that `onDataChanged` gets implicitly called when a new series is added or removed and when data is appended via [appendData](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/BaseSeries.html#appendData-E-boolean-int-) or [resetData](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/BaseSeries.html#resetData-E:A-). Thus in most cases a manual call of `onDataChanged` in not necessary.